# Unable to run LodePNG examples

Tags: c

According to the [README file at the Github repository for LodePNG](https://github.com/lvandeve/lodepng/blob/master/README.md):

> Only two files are needed to allow your program to read and write PNG files: lodepng.cpp and lodepng.h. The other files in the project are just examples, unit tests, etc...

I saved `lodepng.h`, `lodepng.cpp`, and `example_encode.c` to my working folder, renamed `lodepng.cpp` to `lodepng.c` as directed, and tried to run `example_encode.c`. I was greeted by a large number of errors:

```
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqdyxic.o:example_encode.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `lodepng_encode32_file'
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqdyxic.o:example_encode.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `lodepng_error_text'
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqdyxic.o:example_encode.c:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `lodepng_encode32'
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqdyxic.o:example_encode.c:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `lodepng_save_file'
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqdyxic.o:example_encode.c:(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `lodepng_error_text'
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqdyxic.o:example_encode.c:(.text+0x127): undefined reference to `lodepng_state_init'
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqdyxic.o:example_encode.c:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `lodepng_encode'
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqdyxic.o:example_encode.c:(.text+0x18a): undefined reference to `lodepng_save_file'
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqdyxic.o:example_encode.c:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `lodepng_error_text'
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqdyxic.o:example_encode.c:(.text+0x1c6): undefined reference to `lodepng_state_cleanup'
```

All of the errors are referencing functions which are already defined in `lodepng.h`, which is referenced using `#include "lodepng.h"` at the top of the `example_encode.c` file given at the Github link, so I can't figure out why it's having this problem.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: Regarding your terminology, in C, all symbols have a *declaration* and a *definition*. In the header file `lodepng.h` you have function *declarations* (also known as a function *prototype*), while in the source file (`lodepng.c`) you have the function *definitions*. Sometimes the declaration and definition are one and the same, for example if you have a local variable in a function, the declaration is also the definition. When you get this terminology right, you might understand what the problem might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to link lodepng.c with the example program, like this:

```
$ gcc -o example_encode lodepng.c example_encode.c
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now suppose I incorporated the code in `example_encode.c` into a CUDA `example.cu` file; is there a corresponding way to link the `lodepng.c` file when calling `nvcc` from the Command Prompt?

Comment: Not familiar with `nvcc` or CUDA, but I'm guessing the way to do it would be to do `gcc -c lodepng.c` to get an object file `lodepng.o`, and link that to the CUDA program using `nvcc`.